# Is there anything similar to SQL Server Authentication in RavenDb

Tags: ravendb, ravendb-studio

Being new to **`RavenDb`**, I finding many things little tough.  I have installed **RavenDB-Build-2380** and I am able to use Raven studio but unable to find something similar to ***SQL Server's*** SQL Authentication like

- DataSource
- Username
- Password

  [image]

After reading  documentation, I came to know that RavenDb has 2 Authentication mode:

- Windows Authentication
- OAuth Authentication

I can't find where these options are available there in Raven studio, I simple use

`http://localhost:8080/raven/studio.html`

accessing RavenDb but to **setup authentication** I need something similar to SQL authentication.

Can someone please advice on this.

Answer (score 2):

See RavenDB's [Authentication & Authorization documentation](http://ravendb.net/docs/2.0/server/authentication).